# How to declare array using XSLT

Tags: xml

I'm having an XML response getting from a Webservice. I need to transform this XML using XSLT and insert data to a DB.  Sample XML response is as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ttordhdr>
 <ttordhdrRow>
    <OH-ORDNBR>123</OH-ORDNBR>
    <OH-ORDTYPE>B</OH-ORDTYPE>
    <OH-DSTNFLR></OH-DSTNFLR>
    <OH-RCVTYP>P</OH-RCVTYP>
  </ttordhdrRow>
  <ttordhdrRow>
    <OH-ORDNBR>456</OH-ORDNBR>
    <OH-ORDTYPE>c</OH-ORDTYPE>
    <OH-DSTNFLR></OH-DSTNFLR>
    <OH-RCVTYP>P</OH-RCVTYP>
  </ttordhdrRow>
 </ttordhdr>
<ttordline>
 <ttordlineRow>
    <OH-ORDNBR>123</OH-ORDNBR>
    <OL-ORDLNNBR>1</OL-ORDLNNBR>
    <OL-ITEMTYPE>true</OL-ITEMTYPE>
    <OL-QTY>10</OL-QTY>
    <OL-DISP></OL-DISP>
    </ttordlineRow>
     <ttordlineRow>
    <OH-ORDNBR>123</OH-ORDNBR>
    <OL-ORDLNNBR>1</OL-ORDLNNBR>
    <OL-ITEMTYPE>true</OL-ITEMTYPE>
    <OL-QTY>10</OL-QTY>
    <OL-DISP></OL-DISP>
    </ttordlineRow>
   </ttordline>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

My requirement is select all  from / where  is 'B'. And map it with / and get the corresponding .

I think i can use an Array to store  and do the mapping. Please help me on this

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean? Do you mean anywhere where there is a response of 'B' in the text, you want to find it and store it with the element it was found in? so <OH-ORDTYPE>B</OH-ORDTYPE>
 would return OH-ORDTYPE? And then what do you want to do with it? One XPath will give you that (//*[text()='B'])

Comment: What actually i want to do is, select all 'OH-ORDNBR' from 'ttordhdrRow' where 'OH-ORDTYPE' = B. Then map those 'OH-ORDNBR' with the 'ttordlineRow/OH-ORDNBR' and get the corresponding 'OH-ORDNBR' from ‘ttordhdrRow’.

Comment: First of all your xml file is in wrong format. Order of <ttordhdrRow> and <ttordhdr> are interchanged.

Comment: I am also not understanding your statement - "map those 'OH-ORDNBR' with the 'ttordlineRow/OH-ORDNBR' and get the corresponding 'OH-ORDNBR' from ‘ttordhdrRow’" you can give a example and explain better way.

Comment: Here 'ttordhdr' and  'ttordlineRow' are two DB tables. I need to insert the data return from the above webservice to those tables. First i need to get the 'OH-ORDNBR'
from 'ttordhdrRow' table where 'OH-ORDTYPE'="B" Then select 'OH-ORDNBR' from the 'ttordlineRow' table where 'ttordhdrRow'.'OH-ORDNBR' == 'ttordlineRow'.'OH-ORDNBR'

For example:
In first XML set, 'ttordhdrRow'.'OH-ORDTYPE' == "B"
So 'ttordhdrRow'.'OH-ORDNBR'= 123

In second XML set There are 2 maching results where 'tordlineRow'.'OH-ORDNBR'=123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still didn't specify what you want to do with the data, but the following XSLT 1.0 template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ttordhdr/ttordhdrRow[OH-ORDTYPE[text()='B']]/OH-ORDNBR"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OH-ORDNBR">
    <xsl:variable name="val" select="text()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//ttordline/ttordlineRow[OH-ORDNBR = $val]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ttordlineRow">
   <!-- do something here -->
    For OH-ORDNBR <xsl:value-of select="OH-ORDNBR"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your data gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    For OH-ORDNBR 123
    For OH-ORDNBR 123
```

Obviously not much good on its own, but in the template at the bottom (where it says do something here) you get every single ttordlineRow that matches, so you can do what you finally decide you need to do with it.